# Deploy Rails + React + Puma + Nginx to Heroku failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku, puma

I want to deploy RoR + React SPA to heroku as one project. As a typical production environment, use Nginx as web server and user Puma as app server.

I tried to follow `readme` of https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.

But after deployment, heroku popup an error

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Below are my configs

heroku buildpacks

```
heroku/nodejs # index 1
heroku/ruby   # index 2
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.git # index 3
```

Procfile

```
release: bundle exec rails db:migrate
web: bin/start-nginx bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

config/puma.rb

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart

bind ENV.fetch('PUMA_SOCK') { 'unix:///tmp/nginx.socket' }

on_worker_fork do
  FileUtils.touch('/tmp/app-initialized')
end
```

config/nignx.conf.erb => I removed unimportant config for this file because it is too long

```
http {
    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have project that might follow this direction

Comment: I failed to put everything to one heroku project. In the end, I split it to 2 diff heroku projects, one for frontend, and the other for backend, using ajax/api/spa way to communicate each other.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I think that the `procfile` should start Nginx too:

```
 web: bin/start-nginx bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Remember that for the nginx build pack you should disable the demon mode in the `nginx.conf`:

```
daemon off;
```

**EDIT2**: If that line doesn't work, try running Nginx directly (this is a hack, untested)):

```
 web: bin/nginx -p . -c config/nginx.conf & ; bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Also make sure the nginx logs are routed to stdout, placing this in the `nginx.conf`:

```
daemon off;
error_log /dev/stdout info;
http {
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  ...
}
```

**ORIGINAL**:

As the documentation for the build pack states:

> Basically, for webservers that are not designed for efficient, non-blocking I/O, we will benefit from having NGINX to handle all I/O operations

However, Puma is an efficient, non-blocking I/O server. You **should** be able to use it directly on a Heroku dyno.

The biggest advantage that Nginx could offer a Puma server is dealing with static files - which your configuration doesn't perform.

If you're not using Nginx for static files, you might decide to skip the extra latency added the Nginx proxy. Besides, Heroku's security features **should** (but might not) cover all the bases Nginx could offer you at this point.

If you need extra speed for static files - some Ruby servers (such as [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) or [agoo](https://github.com/ohler55/agoo)) provide a fast static file service, allowing you to skip the Nginx layer and reduce latency.

Comment: Well, in my initial intention, I have yarn to build react into `public` folder. Then, nginx will handle request to `public` folder; nginx will pass `/api` to puma. But it does not work either. Same error as above. I don't understand why I follow `heroku-buildpack-nginx.git` but heroku throw error. If I can solve this, I can pass all static request to nginx and `/api` to puma

Comment: @new2cpp I think you need to start the nginx server as well as the app server. See my update.

Comment: Thanks very much for your updates. I think it is my fault to copy but missing `bin/start-nginx` . My demo project is https://github.com/gamesover/hello-world. Still got error `Error R10 (Boot timeout)`

Comment: @new2cpp - I'm not sure where the error occurs. Now that you fixed the `Procfile` (maybe edit the question) it should work... Then again, I'm biased, I'm iodine's author and I use `web: iodine -p $PORT -t 16 -w -1 -www ./public` (you can run benchmarks on the static file service). I might be too trusting of Heroku's router and security layer.

Comment: @new2cpp - if you have a more detailed log, that would help. What messages do you get before the error?

Comment: thanks very much for your help. So far change server is not an option since in production, nginx works well with puma. The staging in heroku is a bit tough. About error, it display tens of `buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization` first, and then `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`. I read some heroku introduction, it seems heroku encourage one dyno serves one service. So typically, frontend and backend are seperated to 2 diff dynos in heroku. Probably it's the reason my issue is not a problem for most people use heroku

Comment: @new2cpp I updated my answer with more details. I think you might be missing the `daemon off;` directive in the `nginx.conf`.

Comment: https://github.com/gamesover/hello-world/blob/0f61cdb68143397a0168e08339d2f306d3df8e1d/config/nginx.conf.erb#L1 I have it

Comment: How do you use '/api'? if your app is located at  'https://yourappname.herokuapp.com/` and your endpoints are say 'api/v1/something` which render only json, how to do make nginx serve this json? Many thanks

Comment: @NevD , I recommend you open a new question for this, as it's practically impossible to answer within a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but I feel my question will be considered as too 'noobee', without enough research - which isn't the case at all. The nginx doc on 'proxy_redirect', 'proy_pass' is mostly for experts, forgetting they also started by copying one day.

Comment: @NevD - there are no "too newbie" questions, only poorly asked questions. If you include your configuration files and show were you are stuck, people will take the question seriously. If the question was asked previously, your question might be closed but you'll get a link to an existing answer that will help you. Better try and have a chance at an answer than not try at all.